# Change the text highlighted by a comment in Google docs

Tags: google-docs

I've been working with a google document, and I have got a comment that references some text:

[image: Before copy]

I then go to copy-and-paste that text somewhere else in my document:

[image: After copy]

Annoyingly, the comment I made now refers both to the original text and to the new text. How can I deselect the new text from the comment?
In more generality, how can I change the text to which a comment refers? For example, in the first picture, how could I change the highlighted part to only include "This is some" and leave out "text!"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After posting on Google Product Forums, I found the answer.
To not bring the text of the comment along with the paste, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, as opposed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
Sadly, it isn't possible to change the text to which a comment refers. It's fixed for good.

Comment: sadly, ctrl+shift+v does nothing in my case..

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + v is the shortcut for Paste Without Formatting (on Windows and ChromeOS), which can also be found in the Edit menu. The shortcut on a Mac is Cmd + Shift + v.